# C's file multiple string arrange

Tags: c

guys i have a problem when enter multiple string in file, it doesn't arrange right, here is my code :

```
char input[5];
int i;

FILE * data;
data = fopen("data.txt", "w");


for(i=0; i<3; i++){
data = fopen("data.txt", "a");
scanf("%s", input);
fprintf(data, "%s ", input);

}

fclose(data);
```

when i enter input like this : a b c

and the output in the file is : c a b

it happen all the time, no matter what : 1 2 3 become 3 1 2, 3 6 9 become 9 3 6

i don't know what's wrong, help me guys, and sorry for my bad grammar :)

Comment: This piece of code is complete nonsense, and it is also incomplete. Why do you `fopen` `data.txt` twice in a row?? Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: remove this `data = fopen("data.txt", "a");` from the for loop

Answer (score 4):

The reason is, that the file handle `data` is block buffered.

In this part:

```
for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    data = fopen("data.txt", "a");
    scanf("%s", input);
    fprintf(data, "%s ", input);
}
```

you open three file handles and write some string to each, let's say

```
1
2
3
```

now here

```
fclose(data);
```

you close the *last* file handle first, which results in the buffer data being flushed to the file. So `3` goes first.

Then, on exit of the program, the other file handles get implicitly closed in the order you opened them, so `1` and `2` gets flushed to your file.

This explains the strange order of items you observe.
The solution is, to only open the file *once*, for example by modifying your loop to:

```
for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
    scanf("%s", input);
    fprintf(data, "%s ", input);
}
```

Now the file is only opened once.